# Time complexity of a function with while loops and an if statement

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis

```
int dup_chk(int a[], int length) 
{
  int i = length;
  while (i > 0)
  {
    i--;
    int j = i -1;
    while (j >= 0)
    {
      if (a[i] == a[j])
      {
        return 1;
      }
      j--;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So what I think I know is the following:

- line 1 is just 1.
- First while loop is N+1.
- i--; is N times since its inside the first while loop.
- j = i -1; is also N.
- Second while loop is (N+1)N = N^2+N since its a while loop within a while loop
- **if statement: ???**
- j--; is N(N) = N^2
- return 0; is 1

I'm really new to calculating the time complexity of algorithms so I'm not even sure if what I think I know is completely right.
But what is messing with me is the if statement, I do not know how to calculate that (and what if there is an else after it as well?)

EDIT: The grand total is equal to 3/2N^2 + 5/2N+3
I understand that this function is O(N^2) but don't quite get how the grand total was calculated.

Comment: Big-O analysis is about asymptotic performance.  If any two entries in the array are the same, then the algorithm exits early.  If all the values are unique, it is O(N²) as each value is compared with each other value.  The asymptotic case as N ⟶ ∞ can ignore the constant costs and even the O(N) costs as the O(N²) costs dominate.  That's the beauty and simplicity of the Big-O notation.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? I'm a bit lost. I understand that this function is O(N^2) as the rest does not matter when N is very large, but I don't quite understand how the exact total is calculated.

EDIT: The total is supposed to be 3/2N^2 + 5/2N+3
its just that I'm not exactly sure how that total was reached. (i'll edit this in the main question as well)

Comment: There are many different behaviours that you might be interested: best and worst and average case, for example. Since the `if` causes premature exit, for worst case of course the `if` would never be true. There are many algorithms for which the average case is very different from worst case.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for is a pessimistic performance measure. the worst case scenario.

Comment: Also: notice that `i`th loop only loops i-1 times! The timing of the constants you cannot calculate exactly like that. Instead you're just interested in how many times the `if` statement is executed.

Comment: The key here is that algorithm theory and "Big O" is mostly BS from the 1960s. The only thing that matters in the real world is how fast the code is executing, which is measured in seconds, not in "_n_". Comparisons are relatively cheap. On old crap compilers, iterating downwards would give slightly faster comparisons because of "branch if zero" instructions. That's 1980s-1990s somewhere. What matters _today_ is the number of branches and the coherence of the data iterated through. And so a linear search through all of the data might be multiple times faster than binary search through some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually such accurate analysis of time complexity is not required. It suffices to know it in terms of Big-O. However, I did some calculations for my own curiosity.

If your concern is just a worst case analysis to obtain the time complexity, consider an array with only unique elements. In such a scenario:

- The `return 1` statement never executes. The inner while loop executes N(N-1)/2 times (summation i-1 from 1 to N), and three things happen - the `while` condition is checked (and evaluates to true), the `if` condition is checked (and evaluates to false) and the variable `j` is decremented. Therefore, the number of operations is 3N(N-1)/2.
- The outer `while` loop executes N times, and there are three statements apart from the condition check - `i` is decremented, `j` is assigned, and the inner `while` condition fails N times. That is 4N more operations.
- Outside all loops, there are three more statements. Initialisation of `i`, the `while` condition fails once, and then the return statement. Add 3 more to our tally.

3/2N<sup>2</sup> - 3/2N + 4N + 3.

That's 3/2N<sup>2</sup> + 5/2N + 3. There is your 'grand total'.

To repeat myself, this calculation is completely unnecessary for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you understand what goes wrong in your code. I have added some printout that make easier to understand what happens in your code.  I think this should be sufficient to find your error

```
int dup_chk(int a[], int length)
{
    int j = 0;
    int i = length;
    char stringa[30];

    printf("Before first while loop j = %d and i = %d \n", j, i);
    while (i > 0)
    {
        i--;
    j = i - 1;
    printf("\tIn first while loop j = %d and i = %d\n", j, i);
    while (j >= 0)
    {
        printf("\t\tIn second while loop j = %d and i = %d\n", j, i);
        if (a[i] == a[j])
        {
            printf("\t\tIn if statment j = %d and i = %d\n", j, i);
            return 1;
        }
        j--;
        printf("\t\tEnd of second while loop j = %d and i = %d\n", j, i);
    }
}
printf("After first while loop j = %d and i = %d \n", j, i);
printf("Press any key to finish the program and close the window\n");
return 0;
}
```

I should also recomend to debug your code understand what goes on better.

Comment: There is nothing _wrong_ in the code, as far I see. All those print statements are superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` check is executed as many times as the inner `while` loop iterates.

The `return 1` is by definition only executed once max. It appears you assume there are no duplicates in the input (ie. worst case), in which case the `return 1` statement never executes.

You'll eventually get a feel for what parts of the code you can ignore, so you won't need to calculate this "grand total", and just realize there are two nested loops that each traverse the array - ie. O(N^2).

Comment: I'm kinda curious to find out how that total was reached, even though I know that it is useless to know since its obvious that it is O(N^2)

Comment: @Khaled : loudmummer's answer gives a thorough analysis, so you might be interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

```
int dup_chk(int a[], int length) 
{
  int i = length;
  while (i > 0)  // Outer loop
  {
    i--;
    int j = i -1;
    while (j >= 0)  // Inner loop
    {
      if (a[i] == a[j])
      {
        return 1;
      }
      j--;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The above program is exactly your code with two comments I took the liberty to add.

Let's consider the worst case scenario (because that's what everyone cares / is worried about). If you notice carefully, you will observe that for every value of `i`, the `Inner loop` executes `i - 1` times. Thus if your `Outer loop` executes `n` times, the `Inner loop` will execute `n * (n - 1)` times in total (i.e. `n - 1` times for each value of `n`).

`n * (n - 1)` yields `n^2 - n` in general algebra. Now, `n^2` increases in leaps and bounds (as compared to `n`) as you go on increasing the value of `n`. Asymptotic notation let's us consider the factor which will have the greatest impact on the number of steps to be executed. Thus, we can ignore `n` and say that this program has a worst case running time of O(n^2).

That's the beauty and simplicity of the Big-O notation. - Quoting Jonathan Leffler from the comments above.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the inner loop will execute n*(n-1) times rather than n*(n+1) times since the while condition is executed one more time when j is < 0.
What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Khaled The value of `j` will be `1` less than `j` just at the start of `Inner loop`.

Answer (score 1):

**Thorough evaluation:**

This program has a special feature: it terminates if a pair `(a[I], a[J])` of equal values is found. Assume that we know `I` and `J` (we will see later what if there is no such pair).

The outer loop is executed for all `I <= i < L`, hence `L-I` times. Each time, the inner loop is executed for all `0 <= j < i`, hence `i` times, except for the last pass (`i = I`): we have `J <= j < I` hence `I-J` iterations.

We assume that the "cost" of a loop is of the form `a N + b`, where `a` is the cost of a single iteration and `b` some constant overhead.

Now for the inner loop, which is run `L-I` times with decreasing numbers of iterations, using the "triangular numbers" formula, the cost is

```
a (L-1 + L-2 + ... I+1 + I-J) + b (L - I) = a ((L-1)L/2 - I(I+1)/2 + I-J) + b (L-I)
```

to which we add the cost of the outer loop to get

```
a ((L-1)L/2 - I(I+1)/2 + I-J) + b (L-I) + c
```

(where `b` is a different constant than above).

In general, this function is quadratic in `L`, but if a pair is found quickly (say `I = L-3`), it becomes linear; in the best case (`I = L-1`,`J = L-2`), it is even the constant `a + b + c`.

The worst case occurs when the pair is found last (`I = 1`, `J = 0`), which is virtually equivalent to no pair found. Then we have

```
a (L-1)L/2 + b (L - 1) + c
```

obviously `O(L²)`.